# Rename node name with "P" and add attribute as and old name

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy, google-translation-api

I am trying to convert xml as a HTML tags for google translate api in groovy. As google translate non html tags I want to moved xml tag as a attribute name and tag name as 'p'. I have generated following XML from the data I have.

```html
<root>
   <glossary>
      <GlossDiv>
         <GlossList>
                  <element>
                  <GlossEntry>
                     <Abbrev>ISO 8879:1986</Abbrev>
                     <GlossDef>
                        <GlossSeeAlso>
                           <element>
                              <element>GML</element>
                              <element>XML</element>
                           </element>
                        </GlossSeeAlso>
                        <para>A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.</para>
                     </GlossDef>
                     <GlossSee>markup</GlossSee>
                     <GlossTerm>Standard Generalized Markup Language</GlossTerm>
                  </GlossEntry>
               </element>
               </GlossList>
      </GlossDiv>
   </glossary>
```

But I want output as below-

```html
<p id="root">
   <p id="glossary">
      <p id="GlossDiv">
         <p id="GlossList">
                  <p id="element">
                  <p id="GlossEntry">
                     <p id="Abbrev">ISO 8879:1986</p>
                     <p id="GlossDef">
                        <p id="GlossSeeAlso">
                           <p id="element">
                              <p id="element">GML</p>
                              <p id="element">XML</p>
                           </p>
                        </p>
                        <p id="para">A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.</p>
                     </p>
                     <p id="GlossSee">markup</p>
                     <p id="GlossTerm">Standard Generalized Markup Language</p>
                  </p>
               </p>
               </p>
      </p>
   </p>
```

And once I get the translated content from the google API I want to convert it back to original XML format. I have tried various groovy and java code to this but I am unable parse the XML as expected.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'd probably just use regex: `def newXml = oldXml.replaceAll(/<(\w+)>/, ) { all, group -> "<p id='$group'>" }.replaceAll(/<\/(\w+)>/, ) { all, group -> "</p>" }`

Comment: It worked like charm. Can you help me with reverse mapping. I am not good with regex.

Comment: what do you mean by reverse mapping, if you mean the meaning of the regexes, just check with regex101.com you get detailed explanations for it: https://regex101.com/r/8hIZ5D/1/

Comment: I want generated output to be converted back to original format once I get translated text content. i.e. <root><root> format.

Comment: way more complicated to go back, you could use this but that's more like a hack and not pretty `def lastTag
def oldXml =  newXml.replaceAll(/p(?: id=")?(?<tag>\w+)?"?>/, {
 all, group -> lastTag = (group) ? group : lastTag
  return "${lastTag}>"
})`

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSLT (eXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) for this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="p_template"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="p_template">
        <p>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:call-template name="repeat"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="repeat">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:call-template name="p_template"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For reverse u can use it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="reverse_template"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="reverse_template">
        <xsl:element name="{@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="repeat"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="repeat">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:call-template name="reverse_template"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is works great!! I need one modification is above xslt. I would like to add prefix to node name "11_11_{NodeName}" as google translate Id of html content which I just discovered. Also remove that prefix while reverse mapping. Can you suggest how to do that.